# ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
create table log_table(
log_id varchar2(1000) primary key,
voter_ID varchar2(1000),
date_logged date
CONSTRAINT abc FOREIGN KEY (voter_ID) REFERENCES voters(voter_ID)
)
```

The table works when i create it without date element. But when i add the date element to it says:

> ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here

Answer (score 7):

> The table works when i create it without date element

```
create table log_table(
log_id varchar2(1000) primary key,
voter_ID varchar2(1000),   -- comma
CONSTRAINT abc FOREIGN KEY (voter_ID) REFERENCES voters(voter_ID)
)
```

You have to add `,` before constraint:

```
create table log_table(
log_id varchar2(1000) primary key,
voter_ID varchar2(1000),
date_logged date, -- here
CONSTRAINT abc FOREIGN KEY (voter_ID) REFERENCES voters(voter_ID)
)
```

I would also reconsider datatype of `log_id`/`voter_id` as (NUMBER/INTEGER).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table log_table(
log_id varchar2(1000) primary key,
voter_ID varchar2(1000) CONSTRAINT abc REFERENCES voters(voter_ID)
)
```

Comment: If you want to apply constraint at column level then you not need to specify Foreign key keyword but in case of table level you must have to specify foreign keyword