# ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here - foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, constraints, ddl

I'm new to this sql and I wanted to know what the problem is in this case.

> "constraint specification not allowed here"
>   Cause:    Constraint specification is not allowed here in the statement.

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
RUT VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT CLIENTE_PK PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBRE VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NOMBRE_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
APELLIDOP VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT APELLIDOP_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
APELLIDOM VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT APPELIDOM_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
DIRECCION VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT DIRECCION_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
TELEFONO NUMBER(8) CONSTRAINT TELEFONO_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR2(255) CONSTRAINT EMAIL_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
FECHA_NACIMIENTO DATE CONSTRAINT FECHA_NACIMIENTO_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
SEXO CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT SEXO_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
COD_CIUDAD NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT CLIENTE_CIUDAD_FK FOREIGN KEY (COD_CIUDAD) 
REFERENCES CIUDAD (COD_CIUDAD)
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751511/ora-02253-constraint-specification-not-allowed-here)

Comment: Please provide more info on what you're trying to accomplish or on what error you get

Comment: I need a table to be created, but it tells me that the constraint is not allowed

Comment: @gile - It is a partial duplicate. In the question you linked to, the desired constraint clearly was meant to be out-of-line (missing comma was the only possible solution). In the question in this thread, the constraint may also be an in-line constraint; the fix is different from adding a comma.

Comment: @Derezed - whenever you post an error message (like you did here), post the FULL text - or, after you become more familiar with errors (I promise you will!), just find where it shows the exact line and position in your code where the error was encountered. That is often quite useful. That is what Guglie was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of code, you define column `cod_ciudad` and you add a foreign key constraint.

There are two categories of constraints: IN-LINE constraints, defined right after the column name and data type (they can only affect "that" column) and OUT-OF-LINE constraints, which come at the bottom of the table, after all the column definitions. Constraints that involve more than one column can only be out-of-line constraints.

The constraint you define in your code is on one column only, and moreover, it is on `cod_ciudad`. You did NOT add a comma between the column definition (name and data type); that is the correct syntax for IN-LINE constraints. But an IN-LINE foreign key constraint does not need the keywords FOREIGN KEY, and they don't need to repeat the column name in parentheses. The constraint, being IN-LINE, can only refer to the "current" column. So: One way to fix your code is to REMOVE `FOREIGN KEY (COD_CIUDAD)` from the code.

Another way to fix it is to make the constraint into an OUT-OF-LINE constraint. Then the syntax is correct, but you must add a comma (,) before the keyword `CONSTRAINT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
   RUT              VARCHAR2(10)  NOT NULL,
   NOMBRE           VARCHAR2(20)  NOT NULL,
   APELLIDOP        VARCHAR2(30)  NOT NULL,
   APELLIDOM        VARCHAR2(30)  NOT NULL,
   DIRECCION        VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
   TELEFONO         NUMBER(8)     NOT NULL,
   EMAIL            VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
   FECHA_NACIMIENTO DATE          NOT NULL,
   SEXO             CHAR(1)       NOT NULL,
   COD_CIUDAD       NUMBER(3) 
);

ALTER TABLE CLIENTE
  ADD CONSTRAINT CLIENTE_PK PRIMARY KEY (RUT)
  USING INDEX;

ALTER TABLE CLIENTE
  ADD CONSTRAINT CLIENTE_CIUDAD_FK FOREIGN KEY (COD_CIUDAD)
  REFERENCES [FOREIGN KEY TABLE NAME] ([PRIMARY KEY COLUMN OF FOREIGN KEY TABLE]);
```

Answer (score 0):

*you must seperate the constraint from the column declaration*

Just use the following command

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
RUT VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT CLIENTE_PK PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBRE VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NOMBRE_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
APELLIDOP VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT APELLIDOP_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
APELLIDOM VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT APPELIDOM_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
DIRECCION VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT DIRECCION_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
TELEFONO NUMBER(8) CONSTRAINT TELEFONO_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR2(255) CONSTRAINT EMAIL_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
FECHA_NACIMIENTO DATE CONSTRAINT 
FECHA_NACIMIENTO_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
SEXO CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT SEXO_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
COD_CIUDAD NUMBER(3),
CONSTRAINT CLIENTE_CIUDAD_FK FOREIGN KEY (COD_CIUDAD) 
REFERENCES CIUDAD (COD_CIUDAD)
);
```